# Size 9 shoes or 9-size shoes

Tags: word-order, attributives

Which form is correct:

> I have size 9 shoes.

or

> I have 9-size shoes.

---

Does the number go before "size" or after?

---

A self-note (note to self?) on something related. It's the 'number 2 bus'. Not: 'bus 2' or '2-bus'.

Comment: **I have size 9 shoes** implies that you are in possession of those shoes. If someone asked you what size shoes you wanted, you might reply: **I take size 9 shoes / I take size nines / I take a size 9.** All are idiomatic.

Comment: The first one. I have never seen the phrase X-size shoes. Where have you seen this?

Comment: I haven't. I was just wondering if the 9 can be used to describe the size. But it can't.